# The same pictures in different albums

Tags: google-photos, sharing, album

I have private album in Google Photos and I want part of this album made public and shared as another album.

Can I do this without uploading the the same pictures a second time, just have two albums that share the pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Open existing album, select picture, then in top right corner press ***more options*** and select ***Add to album***:

[image]

After just choose album to which you want to add.

And this picture belongs to 2 albums.